# Сколько часов заняла бы верстка такого макета? )

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Делала вёрстку, свой первый коммерческий заказ. И потратила более 20 часов на две странички. Сколько бы это заняло у более опытного специалиста времени?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зависит от того был ли изначально какой-то готовый шаблон, который надо было бы просто подогнать под заказчика, либо это всё рисовалось с нуля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Более опытного" - понятие расплывчато.
Я не назовусь особенно опытным, но нуля часа за три-четыре с парой чашек кофе сделал бы. Только верстку, JS и сервер - разговор отдельный.
Страницы-то простенькие.
Но в общем вопрос некорректен - зависит от интенсивности, внимательности разработчика, отвлекушки и хохмочки работающих рядом и т.д.
Предлагаю закрыть вопрос, т.к. всеобъемлющ он.